# Cleanest way to check if a string value is a negative number?

Tags: scala

We could make a method:

```
def isNegNumber(s : String) : Boolean = 
   (s.head == '-') && s.substring(1).forall(_.isDigit)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `s.toDouble < 0`. Don't overengineer much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex pattern.

```
"-10" matches "-\\d+"  //true
```

It can easily be adjusted to account for whitespace.

```
"\t- 7\n" matches raw"\s*-\s*\d+\s*"  //true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Try` and `Option` to do this in a safer way. This will prevent an error if the string is not a number at all

```
import scala.util.Try

val s = "-10"
val t = Try(s.toDouble).toOption
val result = t.fold(false)(_ < 0)
```

Or even better, based on Luis' comment, starting Scala 2.13 (simpler and more efficient):

```
val t = s.toDoubleOption
val result = t.fold(false)(_ < 0)
```

Comment: Note that since `2.13` there is `toDoubleOption` directly on the `String` class.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be:

```
def isNegativeNumber(s: String) = s.toDoubleOption.exists(_ < 0)
```